# Python - GTK Show Tooltip on DrawingArea Shapes

Tags: python, gtk, tooltip, gtk3, drawingarea

I have two rectangles on a drawing area. I need to show different tooltips on the rectangles. For example: `Tooltip1: Rectangle1`, `Tooltip2: Rectangle2`.

Are there any ways to do it (maybe by using mouse location on the widget or by using shape on the drawing areas or another way)?

```
Python 3.7, GTK3.
```